# akka streams stops after parallelism

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

I tried to build a small PDF parser with akka-streams (and limited understandings of it yet) and Apache's pdfbox. 
One thing which I don't really get, the stream stops exactly after the given number of *parallelism* which is given into the *mapAsync*.
so if a PDF-doc has 20 pages and the parallelism is set to 5, the first 5 pages get processed and the rest is ignored, if set to 20, everything is done fine. Anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
  class PdfParser(ws: WSClient, conf: Configuration, parallelism: Int) {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("image-parser")

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  def documentPages(doc: PDDocument, key: String): Iterator[Page] = {

    val pages: util.List[_] = doc.getDocumentCatalog.getAllPages
    val pageList = (for {
      i ← 0 until pages.size()
      page = pages.get(i)
    } yield Page(page, s"$key-$i.jpg")).toIterator
    pageList
  }

  val pageToImage: Flow[Page, Image, NotUsed] = Flow[Page].map { p ⇒
    val img = p.content.asInstanceOf[PDPage].convertToImage()
    Image(img, p.name)
  }

  val imageToS3: Flow[Image, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Image].mapAsync(parallelism) { i ⇒

    val s3 = S3.fromConfiguration(ws, conf)
    val bucket = s3.getBucket("elsa-essays")
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ImageIO.write(i.content, "jpg", baos)
    val res = bucket add BucketFile(i.name, "image/jpeg", baos.toByteArray)
    res.map { _ ⇒
      "uploaded"
    }.recover {
      case e: S3Exception ⇒ e.message
    }
  }

  val sink: Sink[String, Future[String]] = Sink.head[String]

  def parse(path: Path, key: String): Future[String] = {

    val stream: InputStream = new FileInputStream(path.toString)
    val doc = PDDocument.load(stream)
    val source = Source.fromIterator(() ⇒ documentPages(doc, key))

    val runnable: RunnableGraph[Future[String]] = source.via(pageToImage).via(imageToS3).toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
    val res = runnable.run()

    res.map { s ⇒
      doc.close()
      stream.close()
      s
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your Sink. That Sink.head will return one element from your materialized Stream. So the question is, why it´s received more than one value when mapAsync(>1) is used in stream materialization?. Maybe it´s because it uses more than one actor pushing values downstream.

In any case, change your sink to something like:

```
val sink: Sink[String, Future[String]] = Sink.fold("")((a, b) => b ++ a)
```

and it will work.

Comment: Works like a charm and makes a lot more sense than what I thought how it works.